# CRAN package installation errors or rstudio - attempting to install "MODISTools"

Tags: r, installation, error-handling, package, proj

I'm very new to R and am struggling to install the package MODISTools. I've been attempting to install it by using the Install Packages option in RStudio but I get the following errors:

```
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: cannot build geodeticCRS 4326: SQLite error on SELECT name, ellipsoid_auth_name, ellipsoid_code, prime_meridian_auth_name, prime_meridian_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, publication_date, deprecated FROM geodetic_datum WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column: publication_date
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: cannot build projectedCRS 3857: cannot build geodeticCRS 4326: SQLite error on SELECT name, ellipsoid_auth_name, ellipsoid_code, prime_meridian_auth_name, prime_meridian_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, publication_date, deprecated FROM geodetic_datum WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column: publication_date
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create: unrecognized format / unknown name
ERROR 6: Cannot find coordinate operations from `' to `'  
no
configure: error: OGRCoordinateTransformation() does not return a coord.trans: PROJ not available?
    ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘sf’
    * removing ‘/home/coralie/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/sf’
```

I've tried searching for these errors but can't find anyone else having these issues. I've opened RStudio in a new virtual environment to see if these error were due to other packages I'd installed but the same errors appear. It seems like PROJ is the package which is causing trouble so I have also downloaded that through RStudio but that has made no difference to the error.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I have a feeling that this relates to [recent updates in PROJ](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/vignettes/PROJ6_GDAL3.html). So far as I can tell, `publication_date` is a column used by older versions. The best I can suggest is check what version of R you are using, upgrade to the latest if required and try again.

Comment: Thanks, I've just checked and I've got R 4.0.3 so the most recent version